# Commerce.js/Next.js Cart and Billing Form on same page

Tags: javascript, next.js, commerce.js

I need some advice!

I am working on a modified version of the [Next.js/Commerce.js](https://github.com/chec/commercejs-chopchop-demo) storefront ChopChop.
I have been trying to combine the cart and the checkout page as one by adding the  component to the [BillingForm.js](https://github.com/chec/commercejs-chopchop-demo/blob/main/components/Checkout/BillingForm.js)

```html
.
.
.

return <>
  <div className="md:flex md:space-x-12 lg:space-x-24">
    <div className="md:w-1/4"></div>

    <div className="md:w-1/2">

    <Cart/> // cart added here

      <fieldset className="mb-3 md:mb-4">
        <legend className="text-black font-medium text-lg md:text-xl py-3 block">
          Customer Details
        </legend>

.
.
.
```

The visual result is the following:

[image]

What's not working correctly is the `CheckoutSummary.js` and `OrderSummary.js` component content (Subtotal, Tax, Shipping, Total) that is generated from [Checkout.js](https://github.com/chec/commercejs-chopchop-demo/blob/main/components/Checkout/Checkout.js) component like this:

```js
order ? <OrderSummary {...order} /> : <CheckoutSummary {...live} />
```

For the `CheckoutSummary.js` component, the values are **correct as long as there are no updates in the cart** component; if the cart is somehow updated, the content (Subtotal, Tax, Shipping, Total) stays the same, and the changes are not reflected.

When adding **..cart** instead of **..live** to the `CheckoutSummary` component:

```js
const cart = useCartState();
order ? <OrderSummary {...order} /> : <CheckoutSummary {...cart}
```

I do get a Subtotal value that will change on update, but since the ...cart object does not contain Tax, Shipping, Total, **they are not displayed.**

For the `OrderSummary.js`, using the modified checkout/cart BillingForm.js the **..order** object that is sent to the `OrderSummary` component **is not updating** so the order summary (Subtotal, Tax, Shipping, Total) **will not reflect the updates either.**

*I also noticed that when adding or removing items to the cart, a submit will be triggered. Have not figured out why this is happening. Or if it's related to the update issue*

**How can I have the cart and checkout info on the same page, while the order object is updated correctly at cart update and is reflected on the CheckoutSummary and OrderSummary components?**